# Rails How to retrieve act-as-taggable-on tags on multiple levels of associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

### Summary

I have `acts_as_taggable_on :skills` in my `Ad.rb` Model.
I have the following relationships:

Host Model `has_many :locations`

Location `has_many :ads`

Ad `acts_as_taggable_on :skills`

I need the Host list of skills. For every host I need to retrieve the list of skills that he has through his ads.
[image]

I would need to query them and I don't know how to do it with the `ActsAsTaggableOn` object.

### What I know

I can easily retrieve all the skills of a `Location` (number 2). Every host can have multiple locations.

```
Location.ads.tag_counts_on(:skills)
```

This query return an object containing, for each `Location` his `Skills`, this is the result:

```
=> [#<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag:0x0000000943b878 id: 6, name: "javascript", taggings_count: 4>,
 #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag:0x0000000943b738 id: 4, name: "css", taggings_count: 6>,
 #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag:0x0000000943b5f8 id: 8, name: "rubyonrails", taggings_count: 2>]
```

This is the class of this object:

```
=> ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag::ActiveRecord_Relation
```

On this class I can call methods like `.find()`, but If i copy this data in an Array then I can not perform the `.find()` query, to check if I am adding a duplicate.

I just need possibly an array of this skills like:

```
skills = ["css","html","javascript"]
```

So that I can perform this query:

```
@developers = Developer.tagged_with(skills, :any => :true)
```

The last query works, I just need to find out what is the best way to retrieve the skills.

This is acs-as-taggable-on gem github page
https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on

I also add the **git** of this project
https://github.com/fabriziobertoglio1987/SocialNetwork

Thanks a lot
Fabrizio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

```
class Host
  has_many :ads, through: :locations
  has_many :skills, through: :ads
end

host = Host.first
skills = host.skills.pluck(:name)
@developers = Developer.tagged_with(skills, any: :true)
```

Comment: Amazing, It is a very good answer. Thanks a lot. Do you want me to edit the title by including the "gem act-as-taggable-on" or should I leave the question as It is? Fabrizio

Comment: Figurati ;-) mmh dunno, I would title the question _How to retrieve act-as-taggable-on tags on multiple levels of associations_ or something like that I guess

Comment: Grazie molte! Ciao